# Knockout click binding for toggle event called on observable change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm loading an empty ko.observablearray with ajax.  The array is bound to a foreach template to show a button group.  The button is set active/inactive by checking to see if a particular value is in the ko.observablearray, and upon clicking the button, it pushes or removes that value from the array.

The problem is: When I load the ajax data, it fills the array, selects the buttons... then it kicks off the click event, which ends up inverting the selection.  So if Sunday is supposed to be selected and Monday isn't, then I get Sunday not selected and Monday selected.

Other than the array inversion, the functions do what is expected.

The only hacky ways I can seem to think of to fix this, is to attach the click event during the first active check, or to pre-invert my array.  Neither of these ways is very clean.

Is there a way to bypass the initial click event?  Or a way of doing the mapping that doesn't cause an initial toggle?

```
<div class="tab-content" data-bind="foreach: schedulesModel.scheduleViewModel">
<div id="day_group" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="css: {active: $parent.schedulesModel.isSelected($index,'SUN')}, click: $parent.schedulesModel.selectButton($index,'SUN')">Sunday</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="css: {active: $parent.schedulesModel.isSelected($index,'MON')}, click: $parent.schedulesModel.selectButton($index,'MON')">Monday</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="css: {active: $parent.schedulesModel.isSelected($index,'TUE')}, click: $parent.schedulesModel.selectButton($index,'TUE')">Tuesday</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="css: {active: $parent.schedulesModel.isSelected($index,'WED')}, click: $parent.schedulesModel.selectButton($index,'WED')">Wednesday</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="css: {active: $parent.schedulesModel.isSelected($index,'THU')}, click: $parent.schedulesModel.selectButton($index,'THU')">Thursday</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="css: {active: $parent.schedulesModel.isSelected($index,'FRI')}, click: $parent.schedulesModel.selectButton($index,'FRI')">Friday</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="css: {active: $parent.schedulesModel.isSelected($index,'SAT')}, click: $parent.schedulesModel.selectButton($index,'SAT')">Saturday</button>
</div>
```

```
    var schedulesModel = function SchedulesModel() {
    var self = this;
    var numZones = 8;
    this.selectButton = function (index, object) {
        var obj = object;
        var idx = this.scheduleViewModel()[index()].schedule.data.days.indexOf(obj);
        if (idx >= 0) {
            this.scheduleViewModel()[index()].schedule.data.days.remove(obj);
            console.log("object: " + obj + " removed");
        } else {
            this.scheduleViewModel()[index()].schedule.data.days.push(obj);
            console.log("object: " + obj + " added");
        }
    };
    this.isSelected = function (index, object) {
        var obj = object;
        var idx = this.scheduleViewModel()[index()].schedule.data.days.indexOf(obj);
        if (idx >= 0) {
            console.log("object: " + obj + " found");
            return true;

        }
        console.log("object: " + obj + " not found");
        return false;
    };
    var mapping = {};
    this.scheduleViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
    this.updateModel = function (model) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(model, mapping, self.scheduleViewModel);
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {
            JSON.stringify(
            [{
            schedule: {
                data: {
                    days: ["MON","TUE","FRI","SAT","SUN"]
                }}}])
        },
        context: this,
        dataType: 'json'
        success: function (data) {
            self.updateModel(data);
        }
    });

};
ko.applyBindings(new schedulesModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="css: {active: $parent.schedulesModel.isSelected($index,'SUN')}, click: $parent.schedulesModel.selectButton($index,'SUN')">Sunday</button>
```

Problem here is that you're actually *calling* `selectButton` in your binding and setting `click` to the *result* of the call rather than setting it to the `selectButton` function itself.

One way to fix this is to replace the binding with

```
click: $parent.schedulesModel.selectButton.bind(null,$index,'SUN')
```

(obviously you have to do this for all the week bindings)